# Wich version of solidity do I have to use in Quorum

Tags: solidity

If I want to use Quorum, in which Solidity version do I have to write my contracts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quorum does not impose any special restrictions or requirements in regard to the version of Solidity you choose to use.

The most recent quorum source examples are written using 0.4.18